# Storing Information in Stack/Flow Objects

Tags: ruby, shoes

Say I have the following sort of app:

```
Shoes.app do
    @i = 0

    def add_button
        button ("#{@i += 1}")
    end

    button("0") {add_button}
end
```

So that each time you click the button it adds a new button with a higher number. Is there any way to code it so that clicking one of the new buttons displays its number? Since `self` always points to the app, the obvious approach

```
button ("#{@i += 1}") {alert @i}
```

Doesn't work, since then clicking any button just displays the current value of `@i`.

Comment: Does `button` method return an instance of a button? If so, then you can assign the integer to the button as an instance variable when its created.

Comment: That could potentially work, but the obvious way of attempting to do so would create an instance variable for the app, not the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Shoes.app do
    @i = 0

    def add_button
        n = @i+1
        button ("#{@i += 1}") {alert n}
    end

    button("0") {add_button}
end
```

Comment: The reason it works is that `n` is a local variable, and blocks in Ruby are closures. Each invocation of the `add_button` method creates a new local `n` variable, but that variable does not go away after the method is done because the block passed to `button` closed over it and retained its reference.